# i want to run my test in git lab as part of a pipeline. need information for with of chrome driver

Tags: python, git, docker, continuous-integration, automated-tests

my .git-ci.yaml file:

```
image: python:3.6.1

stages:
- test


executing-test:
stage: test
script:
- python -m pip install --upgrade pip
- python3 -m pip install robotframework
- python3 -m pip install robotframework-selenium2library
- python3 -m pip install selenium
- python3 -m pip install -r requirements.txt
- robot -v BROWSER:HeadlessChrome -v env_runtime:IMPL -v verify_prev_run:1 -d Results -i implall Tests


artifacts:
paths:
- Results
only:
- master
```

### The error currently comes is ""WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver' executable needs to be in PATH. Please see https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home"""

I know that this error is occuring because i have not written any chromedriver installation command in script. I tried 'brew cask install chromedriver'. and 'pip install chromedriver_installer' . it resulted in error. please help with right command.

Comment: if i remove the pip install chrome driver command then i get error that chromedriver needs to be in path